# property of expectation when $\Bbb{Q} \ll \Bbb{P}$

Tags: probability, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, radon-nikodym

If $\Bbb{P}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ are two probability measures such that $\Bbb{Q} \ll \Bbb{P}$ (i.e $\Bbb{Q}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\Bbb{P}$), can something be said about the expectation of a random variable $X$ with respect to $\Bbb{P}$ and the expectation of that same random variable with respect to $\Bbb{Q}$ ? For instance, would we have $\Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}[X] \leq \Bbb{E}^\Bbb{P}[X]$ ?

From Radòn-Nikodym theorem we would have that $\Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}[X] = \Bbb{E}^\Bbb{P}[\frac{d\Bbb{Q}}{d\Bbb{P}}X]$ but I am not sure one can say something about the value of $\frac{d\Bbb{Q}}{d\Bbb{P}}$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can't say something, the expectation can be anything depending on $Q$ or $P$, despite the fact that $Q\ll P$, you can construct easily an example with Lebesgue measure in $[0,1]$ and some function $f:[0,1]\to (0,\infty )$ such that $\int_{0}^1 f(x) \,d x=1$

Comment: $L_p$, $p>0$,  spaces do not behave well under absolutely continuous changes of measures. $L_0$ however does, that is, if $X_n$ converges in $P$-measure to $X$, then it also converges in $Q$-measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use $\mathbf{Q}$ or simply $Q$ instead of $\Bbb{Q}$ which usually means the rational numbers.

That being said , no you cannot really say much and also you cannot really state any trichotomic result like that.

For example, consider $P$ to be a Gaussian $N(\mu_{1},\sigma^{2})$ Distribution on $\Bbb{R}$ and $Q$ to be an $\text{Exponential}(\mu_{2})$ distribution on $\Bbb{R}$ . Fix a common sigma algebra on $\Bbb{R}$ namely the Borel Sigma algebra. Then $Q<<P$ simply because $P(A)=0\iff\lambda(A)=0$ which always means $Q(A)=0$ for any Borel set. ($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue Measure)

Now consider any Borel measurable function say $f:(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}))\to\Bbb{R}$ . For simplicity consider $f(x)=x$ . Then $f$ is a real valued random variable from both the probability spaces $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}),P)$ and $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}),Q)$  and now you consider it's expectation with respect to sticking by your notation

$E^{Q}(f(x))=\int_{\Bbb{R}}x\,dQ(x)=\mu_{2}$ and you also have $E^{P}(f(x))=\int_{\Bbb{R}}x\,dP(x)=\mu_{1}$  .

Now notice that I have chosen  $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ arbitrarily and so you can easily see that there need be no relation between them.

Comment: I would point out that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ are very commonly used as notation for probability measures, despite the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ can also denote the rationals.

Comment: @user6247850 Perhaps so. Personally I have never seen $\Bbb{Q}$ used for a probability measure.

Comment: @user6247850 no, this is just false. I never see that in any of the articles nor books about probability theory that I've read.

Comment: @Masacroso exactly . $\Bbb{Q}$ (the rational numbers) is much to often used in Probability Theory and it is unwise to define a probability measure having that notation. For example what if we were to write something like  $\bigcup_{r_{1},r_{2}\in\Bbb{Q}}\Bbb{Q}( X\in [r_{1},r_{2}]\,,r_{1},r_{2}\in\Bbb{Q})$ . Then this is just a sea of confusion.

Comment: Yes, obviously you wouldn't simultaneously use $\mathbb{Q}$ to denote a probability measure and the rationals, much as you wouldn't simultaneously use $i$ to denote the imaginary unit and an index in a sum.  Does that mean $i$ is never used to index sums because an expression like $\sum_{i=1}^I i (i)^i$ is confusing?  At the very least, $\mathbb{Q}$ is often used in financial math to denote the pricing measure.